# How to run a function after entire page is loaded in AEM

Tags: aem, pageload

I added an jquery plugin to AEM

When I run the code on console it works

but not when I add the same lines to the js file.

What would be the issue ?

Comment: Did you call it within document.ready or document.onLoad ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run external js plugin function in AEM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743567/how-to-run-external-js-plugin-function-in-aem)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any of Jquery functions/Events to your AEM page. Helpx article:- **https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom-carousel-components.html** //Creating Custom Carousel components for Adobe Experience Manager Here you can lear to integrate with 3rd party javaScript or JQuery.

Like:-

```
 $(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
  alert("pageload event fired!");
});
```

Reference article of Adobe AEM Community: **http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__6l3s-i_would_liketocrea.html**

I hope this would help you.

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni